# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.persons.map is not a function

Tags: django, reactjs

I am buildig a website using react and django but i seem to be stuck here. i have checked the net for solutions but i cannot seem to find one here is my code and the error i get.[image: error screenshot]

Uncaught TypeError: this.state.persons.map is not a function

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  Container,
  Dimmer,
  Image,
  Item,
  Label,
  Loader,
  Message,
  Segment
} from "semantic-ui-react";
import { productListURL } from "../constants";

export default class ProductList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons:[]
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(productListURL)
    .then(res =>{
      const persons = res.data;
      this.setState({persons});
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.title}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Evidently `res.data` is not an array. Can you tell us what it is?

Comment: Try Adding a console.log(this.state) between the lines `render(){` and `return (`;  this will allow you to see the value of state and its sub items every time the component Re-Renders.  I have a feeling that your async function that appears to be fetching an API result is returning a String rather than a JSON parsed object such as an array; but with the given information We cannot be sure.